# MVC 4 - SampleMembership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a new user for MVC4.

I need to create a website with authentication system.

I need use an existing db with same data (username, password ecc...).

MVC4 came with SampleMembership provider.

How I can develop my personal provider to Authenticate users as SampleMembership?

Is possibile to overrides methods from the SampleMembership?

Comment: You mean `SimpleMembership`, right? Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352218/how-do-i-manage-profiles-using-simplemembership)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you are referring to SimpleMembership. SimpleMembership was [not developed for extensive customization or integrating to existing databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360126/simplemembership-with-custom-database-schema-in-asp-net-mvc-4). To use an existing database you want to create your own membership provider just like you always have in ASP.NET. You can find direction on doing this [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider).

Comment: Finally, write a custom membership provider. Thanks.